# Have problem with my automation selenium code on launching simple chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am just starting my automation testing but landed with some error tired with debugging can someone please help here i have java libraries & selenium server standalone.

[image]

**Error**/

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   D:\browser\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar Caused by:
>   java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module

Comment: Can you convert the screenshot of text back to plain text please.

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\radhakrishnan\Downloads\libs\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following

`Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

instead of

`Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriverInfo();`

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi Sir,

As you justed tried with and imported one more header and still no improvement i am getting error for both chromedriver & header PFA screenshot  https://imgur.com/cTeV4Jm

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the project in expanded view in left panel? I want to see the details of your project.

Comment: And make sure in browser folder there is only chrome driver & move the selenium files in folder outside the browser folder and import again in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a package.

-Inside the Java project: Create a new package

-Inside that package: Create a new Java class

-Copy and Paste this code into that file.

use this code : 
`Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: Hi,

No i have package eventhough the error is not resolved i have added java libs & selenium stand alone libs. Guess something wrong in my library files PFA in below link

https://imgur.com/VDqwTAe